# Undefined function error when trying to addListener to multiple Markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an app that displays a google map and populates it with a set of markers retrieved from a Json file. This works fine. It throws no errors and everything is good. I then wanted to trigger an `InfoWindow` when the markers are clicked so I followed the code on google maps api page but when I add the `addListener` function, the markers don't appear on the map (as if the function to draw them didn't work). In Chromes console, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function       mapapp.js:65`

This is section where the issue arises:

```
function drawMarkers(map){
    var myMarker;
    $.each(markers, function(index, item){
        myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: item.title
        });

        /*This is the error source. Line 65*/
        google.maps.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function(){
            alert("Clicked Marker");
        });
    });
}
```

The markers array is a global variable that populates with json data pulled from my web page. Like I said, the whole thing works without the listener code, but when the `addListener` code is added it fails to draw the markers on the map.

What is it in this line of code thats causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
google.maps.addListener()
```

should be

```
google.maps.event.addListener()
```